# Game not playing the room section after the direction function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created the code and the game start works fine, however after I put in a direction it doesn't go to the room. I've checked if both function work on their own and they work fine, I'm just unsure how they can be linked together.

```
import time
import sys
import random

Forward = ["F", "f", "forward", "FORWARD", "Forward"]
Backwards = ["B", "b", "back", "BACK", "backwards", "BACKWARDS"]
Left = ["L", "l", "LEFT", "left", "Left"]
Right = ["R", "r", "right", "RIGHT", "Right"]
directionL = Right + Left + Backwards + Forward

health = 10

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        #sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.10)
def name():
    name = input('Hey, Who are you? ')
    return name

def direction():
    direction = input("What direction would you like to go: Forward, Left, Right or Backwards?")
    while direction not in directionL:
        direction = input ("Please enter Forward, Left, Right or Backwards.")
    else:
        print ("You went", direction)
def room():
    global health
    a=random.randint(1,8) #1=Monster 2=Exit 3-4=Ghost 5-8=Empty
    if a==1:
        delay_print('You encountered the monster you lose 5HP ')
        health=health-5
    elif a==2:
        delay_print('You escaped the dungeon ')
    elif a==3 or a==4:
        delay_print('You encountered the ghost ')
        x=random.randint(1,11)
        y=random.randint(1,11)
        print((x),'+',(y))
        answer=int(input("What is the answer"))
        realanswer = x+y
        if answer==realanswer:
        print("That's the correct answer")
        health = health+2
    else:
        print("Wrong answer, the answer was",realanswer,"!")
        health = health-2
elif a==5 or a==6 or a==7 or a==8:
    print ('This room is empty')
    health = health-1  
return print("You have", health,"HP left ")

if health <1:
    print ("Game Over")


print('You hear a voice echo in the background.')
delay_print('H...')
delay_print('Hey...')
delay_print('Welcome %s you are stuck in this labyrinth and you need to 
escape.' % name())
print ('\n')
room(direction())
```

Comment: Which debugger are you using to step through the code?

Answer (score 0):

**ANALYSIS**

It doesn't go to the room because of the error message(s) it gave you.  Your indentation is wrong in several places, and the final fatality is here:

```
room(direction())
```

This says "call **direction** and use its return value to call **room**".  However, **direction** does not return a value, and **room** does not accept one.

**PROGRESS**

Use incremental programming.  Part of your confusion comes from writing over 50 lines of code without testing the linkage properly.  Write a few lines, test them, make sure they work, and don't continue until you solve that problem.

In this case, hold your supposedly-working individual routines to the side for a while.  Try to make progress through the labyrinth with "stub" routines, code that does just one reasonable thing.  For instance:

```
def direction():
    return "L"

def room():
     print ("You entered another room.")
```

From here, work on how you move from one room to another.

**HOW DO I DO THAT**

Research, just as the Stack Overflow intro tour tells you.  There are myriad dungeon-crawling games on the internet.  You can grab a template from "Learning Python the Hard Way", for instance.